# Cloudfront not redirecting with trailing slash

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I am hosting a website with multiple subdomains from S3 buckets through Cloudfront.
When I go to `www.domain.com/subdomain/` (note: with trailing slash), the website loads correctly and fetches the minified .js and .css files from `www.domain.com/subdomain/****.js`.

However if I navigate to `www.domain.com/subdomain` without the trailing slash, the site's index.html is still served but the assets attempt to be fetched from `www.domain.com/****.js`.

I have tried to use a lamba@edge function to change the request uri and append the slash however that is not working. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be caused by the html referencing relative file paths (i.e. `src="****.js"` vs `src="/subdomain/****.js"`).

If you are looking to fix this, you will need to perform a redirect to the slash path in the users browser. This can be done by using a Lambda@Edge function to perform the redirect in the `Origin Response` event.

An [example redirect](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-examples.html#lambda-examples-http-redirect) function is below

```
 def lambda_handler(event, context):
 
     # Generate HTTP redirect response with 302 status code and Location header.
     
     response = {
         'status': '302',
         'statusDescription': 'Found',
         'headers': {
             'location': [{
                 'key': 'Location',
                 'value': 'http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-edge.html'
             }]
         }
     }
     
     return response
```

For this you would need to add your custom logic to check if the URL needs to be redirected by checking for a "/" character as the last character of the request.

Additionally if you can change the path of your css, js and images from being relative to being absolute as pointed out at the top of this answer.